# How do I backfill missing mysql data from one table?

Tags: mysql

I have a MySQL table called employee that looks like this:

```
ID | User    | Phone_No     | Phone_No_Count
1  | Fred    | 9999         | 1
2  | John    | 8888         | 2
3  | Pablo   | 123          | 1
4  | John    |              | 0
5  | John    | 8888         | 2
6  | Pablo   |              | 0
7  | John    | 456          | 1
```

Phone_No_Count is a count of the Phone_No column, if there is no Phone_No then Phone_No_Count is set to zero.

I want to backfill the missing Phone_No entries using Phone_No entries which have the highest Phone_No_Count.

e.g. User John has 2 Phone_No's (8888 and 456) so I just want to use 8888 as it has the highest Phone_No_Count (2)

The backfilled data in employee would then look like this:

```
ID | User    | Phone_No     | Phone_No_Count
1  | Fred    | 9999         | 1
2  | John    | 8888         | 2
3  | Pablo   | 123          | 1
4  | John    | 8888         | 0
5  | John    | 8888         | 2
6  | Pablo   | 123          | 0
7  | John    | 456          | 1
```

I can then update the Phone_No_Count separately, which I know how to do anyway.

All the examples I've seen online are for backfilling multiple tables or if it's just one table they don't have the required logic for this.

Can somebody please help as this has been frying my brain all day!!

Comment: I'd revise your table schema, overwriting data like that isn't a good idea. Use a `employee_phone` table to store the raw phone number data, and have your `employee` table have ID, user, and Phone_No columns. That way you could assign a primary phone number to each employee and not lose data.

Comment: Thanks for your comment, but changing the schema isn't really an option here. I agree with what you're saying though.

Answer (score 0):

One way to go about this kind of update you can use user defined variables in your query and store the phone for the user which has the maximum of phone count (i.e a correlated subquery) then join this data with your table and do update

```
update Table1 t1a 
inner join(
select t1.id,
t1.`User`,
@p:= case 
     when t1.Phone_No is null then @c
     else t1.Phone_No END Phone_No,
@c:=(select Phone_No from Table1 where t1.`User`=`User` order by  `Phone_No_Count` DESC limit 1 ) max_phone
from Table1 t1,(select @p:=0,@c:=0) t
order by t1.`User`,t1.`Phone_No_Count` DESC
) t2 on(t1a.id=t2.id)
set t1a.Phone_No = t2.Phone_No
```

### [Fiddle Demo](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/5e0299/1)

Comment: Thanks for this. However, I can't get this to run, I cancelled the query after 5 minutes waiting - I think it's just too heavy a query with the amount of rows (300,000). Perhaps the answer is to split this into 2 queries in a PHP script - one query to get the rows to update and run and another query to update each row. The second query is easy but it's the first query i'm struggling with.

Answer (score 0):

The trick is to get the phone number for the highest count.  Unfortunately, MySQL doesn't let you have subqueries on the same query being updated, but you can do this with a trick.  This allows you to use `update`/`join` syntax:

```
update employee e join
       (select e.user,
               substring_index(group_concat(phone_no order by phone_no_count desc
                                           ), ',', 1) as new_phone_no
        from employee e
        group by e.user
       ) toupdate
       on e.user = toupdate.user
    set e.phone_no = toupdate.new_phone_no
    where e.phone_no is null;
```

Comment: Thanks for this. I think you missed off SET before " e.phone_no = toupdate.new_phone_no". I also changed e.phone_no = '' as I don't have any null values only blank. When I ran it, like the other answer it just takes too long, so I cancelled it after 5 minutes. I think the answer is to use 2 queries in a PHP script. I'm just not sure how yet.

Comment: I've made use of your trick to get the first query I need but it's taking 70 seconds which is too long.

This is what I've done so far:

    SELECT e.User, 
    SUBSTRING_INDEX(GROUP_CONCAT(Phone_No ORDER BY Phone_No_Count DESC), ',', 1) AS new_Phone_No, 
    SUM(IF(Phone_No='',1,0)) AS no_of_blanks, 
    SUM(IF(Phone_No!='',1,0)) AS no_of_full
    FROM employee e
    GROUP BY e.User 
    HAVING no_of_blanks > 0 
    AND no_of_full > 0